# Netsuite send email on work order creation

Tags: workflow, netsuite

For internal uses, I want to send an email every time a work order is created/updated/built. I am trying to achieve this doing a workflow. does anyone have a basic example I can follow along with? Things I'm trying to include are product, quantity, date created, date complete, BOM if possible. The help file is kind of a misnomer on this... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new workflow: 
Customization -> Workflow -> New

Set:
Record type: Work order, 
Initiation: Event Based, 
Events: Create, Update, 
Trigger Type: After Record Submit.

And Save the workflow.

Open State 1. 
Go to Action -> New Action.
Click on 'Send Email'.
Select Sender.
Content: You can choose already created Template or define body here.
Select Recipient.

This should send an email.